# how to show or close (not hide) a form in vb.net on press of certain keys

Tags: vb.net

I wish to display a login form on the press of ctrl+alt+z...and close the program on the press of ctrl+alt+c. Using at timer Heres what i have tried..But its not working..What am I doing wrong?? Using timer's interval as 5000 milliseconds.Looking for some help..Thank you

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown And My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown And RichTextBox1.Text = "z" Then
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()

    ElseIf My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown And My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown And RichTextBox1.Text = "c" Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't capture combination keys like that. Do it like this...

1) Set the Form's KeyPreview Property to True.

2) Add code under the Form's KeyDown Event.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Control And e.Alt And e.KeyCode = Keys.Z Then
        MsgBox("Hi") 
    End If
End Sub
```